# How do i create matrix like table in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a table that will have several columns but some of the columns will have nested columns. I tried but i am not able to get it working.

As you can see Column 4 has 3 nested tables (4.1,4.2, 4.3) but when i create one more row and add values to it, it gets messed up.

http://jsfiddle.net/G9w5d/

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
                <th>Col 4</th>
                <th>Col 5</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th><table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Col 4.1</th><th>Col 4.2</th><th>Col 4.3</th></tr></thead></table></th>
                <th><table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Col 5.1</th><th>Col 5.2</th><th>Col 5.3</th></tr></thead></table></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Val 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Val 2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Val 3
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table border="1"><tbody><tr><td>This is Val 4.1</td><td>This is Val 4.2</td><td>This is Val 4.3</td></tr></tbody></table>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want your header to span multiple columns.

You can use the [`[colspan]`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-tdth-colspan) and [`[rowspan]`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-tdth-rowspan) attributes to allow a cell to span beyond their normal bounds.

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th colspan="3">Col 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Col 4.1</th>
      <th>Col 4.2</th>
      <th>Col 4.3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Val 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Val 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Val 3
      </td>
      <td>This is Val 4.1</td>
      <td>This is Val 4.2</td>
      <td>This is Val 4.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following table has two nested columns within the third column. This is achieved by having the top row cell in the third column span the two cells below it. The width of the first row cell is 40%. The columns under it are both 20%.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="400">
<tr>
    <td height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2" width="40%" height="19">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```